# Finding sublists with a specified sum

Tags: list, haskell

I'm working on a function in Haskell where it receives a list of Ints and an Int.

```
sublistSum :: [Ints] -> Int -> [[Ints]]
```

What it returns is a sublist containing lists of numbers in the original list that adds up to the Int.

For example:

```
sublistSums [1, 5, -2, 4, 3, 2] 2
[[1,-2,3],[-2,4],[2]]
```

What I worked up to:

```
sublistSums [] num = []
sublistSums (x:xs) num  
    | findSum x xs num == num = findSum x xs num 0 : sublistSums (x:xs) num
    | otherwise = sublistSums xs num

findSum x [] num count = []
findSum x (y:ys) num count
    | ...
```

so `findSum` is a helper function I made that should return a list of such numbers (that add up to the number).

I'm a bit confused up to this point.  How can I mark it so that `findSum` doesn't repeatedly give me the same list of numbers over and over again?

Comment: It might be better to reverse the order of the arguments, since then `sublistSum n` could be used in a sequence of operations like `sort . sublistSum 2 . filter (not . even) $ [1..10]`

Comment: Interesting...I'll keep it in mind, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could first produce a list of all possible sublists using the function `subsequences` from `Data.List`. Then it is just a matter of filtering the list by their sum.

```hs
import Data.List

sublistSum :: [Int] -> Int -> [[Int]]
sublistSum list target =
    filter (\x -> sum x == target) $ subsequences list
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.  I'll see what I can work with that.

Comment: Take a look at the implementation of [`subsequences`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#subsequences) for inspiration

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you and please have my upvote.